# about Synplify VHDL (code imported from Xilinx ISE)

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, synthesis

Good day,

Need some help. Start to work with Synopsys Synplify. Import my Xilinx ISE project (fully work).

Try to run and receive - "No matching overload for to_integer" for this line

```
rgb(7 downto 0) <= color_lut(result_reg(to_integer(unsigned(x(2 downto 0))-1 )));
```

What can I do to adopt this piece for Synplify?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:
did You include numeric_std?
Also Your code line seems to be wrong, because there are 5 opening ( and only 4 closing ) and no closing ;.
You can try to_unsigned() later.

Comment: Yes, numeric_std included. >code line seems to be wrong - "copy pust bug" :) brackets are correct

Comment: copy more _correct_ code then :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it compile in a simulator?  You often get more useful error message, and you should always simulate before synthesising.  EDIT: Your comments indicate you have and it's fine.

XST is not always a good representation of correctness of code - it's VHDL is sometimes a little off-spec in interpretation.

I'd have thought you want something like this (with lots of extra whitespace for clarity of answer, I'd not usually write it like this in source-code).  You never know, Synplify might be happier with this version:

```
rgb(7 downto 0) <=
    color_lut(
        result_reg(
            to_integer(
                unsigned(
                    x(2 downto 0)
                ) --close "unsigned"
             ) -- extra bracket here - you now have a signed integer you can subtract '1' from
            -1
        ) -- close result_reg index
    ); -- close colour_lut index
```

Otherwise, please give more details on the data types involved.

Comment: is that a copy/paste error? -- yes

Comment: >you should always simulate before synthesising -- yes, but in simulator (or after XST synthes) it's all right.

Comment: Can you post more code then - what type are `color_lut`, `result_reg` and `x`?